# Как узнать что в БД уже есть такая строка?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Перед добавлением в БД при помощи EF, необходимо проверить что вставляемой строки нет. Какой оператор для этого можно использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это решается UNIQUE Constraint на уровне базы.

Но если надо прям на уровне ORM, то используйте метод [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx). Для подобных проверок он обычно наиболее эффективен.

В частности, при использовании провайдера SQL Server, он преобразуется в [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) с выборкой данных в подзапросе по вашему условию - СУБДД прекращает операцию поиска сразу-же после нахождения первого соответствия(в отличие скажем от COUNT, который пытается найти абсолютно все соответствия, перебирая индексы/записи от начала и до конца).

Comment: @Serget Rufanov if  (db.BTC_USD.Any(p => p.trade_id == set.trade_id))
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Q", "QQQ");
                        db.BTC_USD.Add(set);
                    }

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич, ну да, как-то так. Хотя "добавление записи, только если в таблице уже есть хоть одна запись с тем-же самым ключем" мне кажется немного странной - в этом коде точно нет опечатки?

Comment: а можете показать пример сравнения. Например у меня есть набор данных, который приходит от сайта. Я пытаюсь сделать выборку из набора и поместить в БД  foreach (var set in data.BTC_USD)
                {
                    if  (db.BTC_USD.Any(p => p.trade_id == set.trade_id))
                    {
                        db.BTC_USD.Add(set);
                    }                
                                      
                }
                db.SaveChanges();  Но в БД ничего не падает

Comment: проверял на неравенство  { if (db.BTC_USD.Any(p => p.trade_id != set.trade_id)) { db.BTC_USD.Add(set); } то же самое

Comment: то есть не добавляет вообще ничего, БД пустая абсолютно

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич, в студии установите брекпойнт на строчке с `db.BTC_USD.Add(set);`, да запустите в отладке - так сможете определить, выполняется ли условие вообще. Если в условный блок не заходит - что-то не то с условием. Попробуйте проверить условие руками,  выборкой нужные данные SQL-запросом в студии, или простым Find-ом в EF - возможно указанных строк в базе нет, или наоборот они там уже есть(в зависимости от условия). Если же заходит, но данные в базе не появляются - вероятно вы забываете сохранять их вызовом SaveChanges() у контекста.

Comment: внутрь ветки не заходит, => условие не соблюдается, БД пустая.

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич, глянул ваш код выше, из комментария который я пропустил.. `if (db.BTC_USD.Any(p => p.trade_id != set.trade_id)) 
{
 db.BTC_USD.Add(set); 
} ` - вы не там условие развернули. Здесь вы добавляете запись только если нашлась хоть одна запись, у которой `p.trade_id != set.trade_id`. Условный блок выполнятся только тогда, когда в таблице есть хоть одна запись не соответствующая указанному условию. Сейчас там записей нет - условие не выполняется. Как появится хоть одна несоответствующая запись - условие будет выполнятся всегда. Это явная ошибка.

Comment: @ДмитрийАзаревич, вы должны были развернуть булево значение возвращаемое Any, Т.е. примерно так: `if (!db.BTC_USD.Any(p => p.trade_id == set.trade_id)) 
{
 db.BTC_USD.Add(set); 
} ` - в этом случае добавление в таблицу будет происходить только если в ней нет ни единой записи с указанным ключем `trade_id`

Comment: Спасибо большое, решил проблему